# Using varied types of arguments when making a new object

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, arguments

I have a class called Vec. (Vector)

```
function Vec (x_or_vec,y) {
    this.x;
    this.y;
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 0:
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            this.x = x_or_vec.x;
            this.y = x_or_vec.y;
            break;
        default:
            this.x = x_or_vec;
            this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Sometimes I want to make a new object without specifying any information about it, then, I want x and y to be zero. Other times I want to input a vector for the new vector to copy, and some times I want to specify x and y coordinates for the new vector. I don't like the method I use in the example, and for some of the classes I make, this method cannot be used.

```
function Box (pos,color,size) {
    this.pos = new Vec(pos);
    this.color = color;
    this.size = new Vec(size);

}
```

In some cases I want to specify color, but not size, and in other cases, size but not color, and in some cases both, and some none of them.

Comment: You can simply `Overload` (Same function **Name** with different **Parameters**) the function. and for creating objects use `Multiple Constructors`

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi: there is no function overloading in javascript

Comment: @BOSS: Thank you for the info. I'm sorry for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a'la JQuery passing a literal object to the class.
Initialize like this:

```
// don't break if called without arguments 
if(arguments == undefined)
    arguments = {};

// setting default value
this.x = arguments.x || 'some default value';

// checking for object
this.x = (typeof arguments.x === 'object') ? arguments.x.property : arguments.x;
```

You have plenty of cases so this is just a pointer.